# Maximize navigation width with items of different length

Tags: css

I have a navigation with ten items inside it and I want to maximize its length and set the spaces between the items equally.

So far, this is what I've done. But it only looks nice if the menu items' lengths are equal, but mine isn't. Ideas, anyone? Thanks in advance.

```
<nav class="menu">
    <ul>    
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>About Us</li>
        <!-- eight more menu items -->
    </ul>
</nav>
```

And here's my stylesheet.

```
.menu {
    width: 100%;
}

.menu li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 10%; /* since I have 10 items */
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

View this [codepen](http://codepen.io/thomasbormans/pen/vOPbLe?editors=110).

You will need to float your `li` items left.

CSS:

```
.menu {
  width: 100%;
}

.menu ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.menu ul li {
  width: 8%;  
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0% 1%;
  float: left;
  padding: 0;
}
```

It's important to keep track of your total width (100%). Each item should be 10% (since you are having 10 items) in **total**. This means when you want a margin of 1% on the left and on the right side, your li item should have a width of 8%.

Your total width should always be 100%. Otherwise your user will be able to scroll horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

add margin for `li` in css file.

```
.menu li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left:1%;
    width: 6%; /* since I have 10 items */
    text-align: center;
}
```

Or use `@media` rule is used to define different style rules for different media types/devices

Comment: It looks the same, apparently.

Comment: Adjust  `width` and `margin`

Answer (score 0):

Use the modern flexbox technique for the solution. No need to set any `width` or `margin`.

Check the browser compatibility table: [**Flexbox**](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox)

Use the [**CSS Prefixer**](http://pleeease.io/play/) to support some of the older browsers:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.menu ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row nowrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.menu li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<nav class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>About Us</li>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>About Us</li>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>About Us</li>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>About Us</li>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>About Us</li>


  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could have ato add float css rule to the **ul** element.

```
.menu ul{padding:0px;}
.menu {
    width: 100%;
}

.menu ul li {
    float:left;
    width: 10%; /* since I have 10 items */
    text-align: center; 

}
```

try with above code